# Is it a mistake in msdn documentation for covariance at delegates?

Tags: c#, delegates, covariance, msdn, contravariance

In [this msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3) about covariance and contravariance it is explained that `out` keyword is used to declare a generic parameter covariant.

> You can declare a generic type parameter covariant by using the out keyword.

Then is given an example of usage of the `out` keyword, and after that, this statement comes in which it is said about the delegate as a method parameter which is "contravariant", which I think should be called "covariant" because it is still marked with `out` :

> There is one exception to this rule. If you have a **contravariant** generic delegate as a method parameter, you can use the type as a generic type parameter for the delegate.

Then this example follows:

```
interface ICovariant<out R>
{
    void DoSomething(Action<R> callback);
}
```

Shouldn't be the delegate parameter called covariant instead contravariant?

Comment: `Action<T>` *is* contravariant; not covariant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Servy's comment I understood what the sentence was about, it was not the interface that was contravariant, it was the `Action<T>` which is a generic contravariant delegate. So the msdn documentation was right, it was just a misunderstanding of me when I thought that the sentence was about the generic type parameter of the interface was considered contravariant. It is this way:

```
interface ICovariant<out R> //this is covariant
{
    void DoSomething(Action<R> callback); //this is contravariant
}
```

Comment: Variance applies to generic type parameters, so it is `R` which is covariant in `ICovariant`. Contravariance reverses the sub/supertype relationship, and the parameter types of `Action` delegates are contravariant. The use of a contravariant parameter in a contravariant position is covariant as the ordering is reversed and then reversed again.

Comment: So @Lee ,  the parameter R of the interface is covariant, as can be seen from the out keyword. But it is converted to contravariant as it is passed to Action. After this why do you say it is converted back to covariant? Because what I see is the use of a covariant parameter in a contravariant position...

Comment: The argument type `T` is contravariant in `Action<T>` and `callback` is in a contravariant position, so you have a contravariant parameter in a contravariant position, which is covariant.

Comment: @Lee the Action<T> indeed is contravariant as from msdn public delegate void Action<in T>( T obj ), I can see the in keyword, but why do you say that the callback is in a contravariant position which results in a covariant? In this case all the usages of Action<T> will result in a covariant behavior, wouldn't it? Please feel free to have an answer to the question, I will apreciate it!